# Detect input keyboard with Jython,MonkeyRunner and jTkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, jython, keyboard-events, monkeyrunner

I use MonkeyRunner with Jython-standalone 2.5.4-rc1 ,

So I would like to detect the events of keyboard,
I know this is possible with Tkinter :

```
import Tkinter as tk

def onKeyPress(event):
   text.insert('end', 'You pressed %s\n' % (event.char, ))
   print 'keypress', event.char
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')
text = tk.Text(root, background='black', foreground='white', font=('Comic Sans MS', 12))
text.pack()
root.bind('<KeyPress>', onKeyPress)
root.mainloop()
```

So I use jTkinter but he put me an error (i just change the librairie)

```
import jTkinter as tk
...
```

and i get this error :

```
root = tk.Tk()
AttributeError: 'javapackage' object has no attribute 'Tk'
```

How i can do it ?
Thanks

Comment: you rather need to `import Tkinter as tk` under `jython`

Comment: I tried but the librairie is not found ImportError: No module named Tkinter

Comment: jTkinter is old. Nothing has happened in 15 years: http://jtkinter.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jtkinter/jTkinter/. I'm not surprised that it is hard to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell what do you want with the key events, I guess you want to send them to an android device.

Then, what you are trying to achieve is almost exactly what [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) does. Take a look at the examples, mainly the ones under [Culebra GUI](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/Culebra-GUI). Perhaps all you need is to run `culebra -G` and all (most) of your key events will be sent to the device.

If this is not what you are trying to do, at least it may give you a better idea as the UI uses Tkinter.